# Different values are considered equal in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a function that listens to the `scroll` event of the browser. In this function I check whether the value of `lastScrollTop` is higher or lower than the previous value (stored in `st`). In Google Chrome this works perfectly fine, but in Mozilla Firefox this causes issues.

```
    $(function() {
    var commentCount = $('.ItemCount').val(),
        nextPageNumber = 2,
        lastScrollTop = 0,
        pageSize = @Model.Filter.PageSize,
        newTab = false,
        isFetchingData = false;
    $(window).on('scroll',
        function () {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();
            if (st > lastScrollTop) {
                if (newTab) {
                    commentCount = parseInt($('.ItemCount:first').val()), nextPageNumber = 2, lastScrollTop = 0, pageSize = @Model.Filter.PageSize;
                }
                if (!isFetchingData && commentCount > 0 && commentCount >= pageSize) {
                    var scrollBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) - ($($('header').children()[0]).height() + $('#footer-new').height() + $('#footer').height() + $('.load-wrapp').height());
                    var div = $('.commentList');
                    var bottom = ((div.offset().top + div.height()) - scrollBottom);
                    if (bottom < 0) {
                        isFetchingData = true;
                        var url = $('.comments .nav.nav-tabs li.active a').attr('href')
                            .replace("CurrentPage=1&", "CurrentPage=" + nextPageNumber + "&");
                        url = url.replace("&ViewName=Tab", "&ViewName=List");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            async: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('.commentList').append(data);
                                commentCount = parseInt($('.ItemCount:last').val());
                                isFetchingData = false;
                                nextPageNumber++;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $('.load-wrapp').attr('style', 'display:none !important')
                }
            }
            lastScrollTop = st;
            newTab = false;
        });
    $('.nav.nav-tabs li a').on('click',
        function () {
            newTab = true;
        });
})
```

Comment: "this causes issues", what are the issues?
What values do you get in Chrome vs. Firefox?

Comment: in Chrome: st will get the proper value and lastScrollTop will take the value of st if it goes into the else section. Once it comes back into the function, st gets a new value and is compared to lastScrollTop.
in Firefox: right from the beginning, lastScrollTop gets the exact same value as st. When it comes back in the function after user scrolls again, both values will again be equal so it never enters my first if statement